# Why I put in function, loop does not work properly but in global it's exactly work

Tags: javascript

I work with a array functions. When i try to put into a function, it work wrong. But i put in global, it work correctly. Please help :<, tell me details...

```
function a(){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
        arr[i] = function(){
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
var myArray1 = a();

myArray1[0]();
/// 3

var myArray2 = [];
for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
    myArray2[i]=function(){
        console.log(i);
    }
}

myArray2[0]();
/// 0
```

i expect output of `myArray1[0]()` is 0 but actual output is 3

Comment: `var` vs. `let`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `var` instead of `let` in your second loop. for more detail checkout this article(https://medium.com/front-end-developers/es6-variable-scopes-in-loops-with-closure-9cde7a198744).

```js
function a(){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
        arr[i] = function(){
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
var myArray1 = a();

myArray1[0]();
/// 3

var myArray2 = [];
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){ // user var instead of let here
    myArray2[i]=function(){
        console.log(i);
    }
}

myArray2[0]();
/// 3
```